# Negative sum from positive values?

Tags: powerbi

I'm learning powerbi following microsoft labs and, in the 2nd lesson, I've noticed something apparently weird (I mean, it is weird for me but maybe not for you experts)...basically, I've positive values in all categories but their sum seems negative...how is it possible? What's concern me is that when I try to drill down the negative column, line, whatever it is at the moment, I can't find any negative numbers inside it and only display negative total as the general sum...if I drill down, all the pieces are positive... Screenshoots to help you understanding it better...[image][image][image]

Comment: Can you provide a sample pbix or link to the lab in question where we can reproduce this observation.